# How to change the language of ErrorText based on culture in aspx.cs

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to the world of asp and was given the task to make sure a site can be translated with the click of a button.
So far i was able to make most of the page translate using recourse files but small things like the error messages you get when trying to login is what i'm stuck on.

The error messages for ASPX(Password is required and Username is required) is inside  so i cant "call" my resource file.
The "Username or password is incorrect" message is inside my ASPX.CS is inside a else statement and i cant figure out how to "call" the resource file.

Any help will truly be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple. All you need to do is remember to convert to string

https://forums.asp.net/t/1930499.aspx?Displaying+messages+in+the+message+box+from+the+resource+files+in+c+